# woocomrce pay here button help

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am beginner in WordPress.I am using woocommrce plugin. What i am trying to implement is when i click the item (add to cart) after product checkout to  showing order details and payment option and pay here button. My issue is i want to hide this time payment option and pay here button to send to invoice for customer . after 2nd time admin send to shipping  cost with total payment details. and payment option with pay here button . i tried to find any plugin this type . i dont seen any plugging . please help me to fix this

thanks

Comment: Let me help this clear up more..You are looking for a website where user can add products in cart and submit order without paying (Order Quote) and receives thank you page. After receiving order, admin will review quote order and make changes in product price or add other charges and send proposal back to customer. Now Customer who has submitted order will review Order in My Orders screen and accept Website Admin proposal, which will then show use "Pay Now" button and customer will be again redirected to payment page for payment.  

If this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @dhirenpatel22 Sir, yeah i need that one, i tried to find lot of plugin. i cant find all of plugging are pro version . im a student i dont have money to buy this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a free WooCommerce extension for Quote implementation.

REQUEST FOR QUOTE PLUGIN: https://woocommercequoteplugin.com/

1. Customer adds products to the Quote from website. All products will be displayed in Quote List and customer sends the quote request to the website Admin.
2. Website admin views the quote and creates the proposal as shown in below screenshot from orders screen.

[image]

3. Customer sees proposal and accepts or rejects proposal from Quotes detail page in My Account.

[image]

This plugin brief doc for installation and how it works...Hope this helps..!!